# Getting connection closed exception while inserting messages to Evenhub using its client

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I m basically using java to insert streaming data into the event hub. I am using the EventHubProducerClient to insert the same. But I am seeing some loss of messages while insertion and I see the below amqp exception while insertion

````
```
EventHubProducerClient client = new EventHubClientBuilder().connectionString(connectionString, eventHubName)
                .buildProducerClient();
        try {
            EventDataBatch dataBatch = client.createBatch();
            EventData data = new EventData(content);
            if (null != data && dataBatch.tryAdd(data)) {
                client.send(dataBatch);
                LOG.info("Message Sent to Eventhub");
                client.close();
            } else
                System.out.println("The data getting passed is null");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            telemetryClient.trackException(e);
        } catch (AmqpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            telemetryClient.trackException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            telemetryClient.trackException(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            telemetryClient.trackException(e);
        } finally {
            client.close();
        }
```
````

But I am seeing loss of some messages from source to Eventhub. In my application logs I see the following exception displaying once in every two days

````
**connectionId[MF_9ac2be_1645071417683] Connection closed. Could not get active connection., errorContext[NAMESPACE: Eventhub_Name.servicebus.windows.net]**

Full Exception stacktrace :
```
com.azure.core.amqp.exception.AmqpException:
   at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorConnection.onClosedError (ReactorConnection.java:400)
   at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorConnection.<init> (ReactorConnection.java:116)
   at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.EventHubReactorAmqpConnection.<init> (EventHubReactorAmqpConnection.java:64)
   at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder.lambda$buildConnectionProcessor$0 (EventHubClientBuilder.java:643)
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BaseSink.onRequest (FluxCreate.java:536)
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.onRequest (FluxCreate.java:264)
   at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder.lambda$buildConnectionProcessor$1 (EventHubClientBuilder.java:624)
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate.subscribe (FluxCreate.java:94)
   at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe (Flux.java:8156)
   at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribeWith (Flux.java:8329)
   at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder.buildConnectionProcessor (EventHubClientBuilder.java:651)
   at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient (EventHubClientBuilder.java:555)
   at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder.buildClient (EventHubClientBuilder.java:593)
   at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder.buildProducerClient (EventHubClientBuilder.java:501)
   at com.xxx.EventHubConnector.publishEvents (EventHubConnector.java:30)   
```
````

Why am I seeing the above error ? I know I am closing the eventhub client twice but I guess it should not cause the issue. Please correct me if I am wrong

Adding Full Exception stacktrace :

```
 com.azure.core.amqp.exception.AmqpException:
   at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorConnection.onClosedError (ReactorConnection.java:400)
   at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorConnection.<init> (ReactorConnection.java:116)
   at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.EventHubReactorAmqpConnection.<init> (EventHubReactorAmqpConnection.java:64)
   at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder.lambda$buildConnectionProcessor$0 (EventHubClientBuilder.java:643)
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BaseSink.onRequest (FluxCreate.java:536)
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.onRequest (FluxCreate.java:264)
   at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder.lambda$buildConnectionProcessor$1 (EventHubClientBuilder.java:624)
   at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate.subscribe (FluxCreate.java:94)
   at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe (Flux.java:8156)
   at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribeWith (Flux.java:8329)
   at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder.buildConnectionProcessor (EventHubClientBuilder.java:651)
   at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient (EventHubClientBuilder.java:555)
   at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder.buildClient (EventHubClientBuilder.java:593)
   at com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.EventHubClientBuilder.buildProducerClient (EventHubClientBuilder.java:501)
   at com.swinds.connectors.EventHubConnector.publishEvents (EventHubConnector.java:30)
   at com.swinds.connectors.EventHubConnector.setEventHub (EventHubConnector.java:77)
   at com.swinds.connectors.EventHubConnector.routeEventHub (EventHubConnector.java:66)
   at com.swinds.function.BlobFunction.run (BlobFunction.java:17)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodInvokeInfo.invoke (JavaMethodInvokeInfo.java:22)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodExecutorImpl.execute (JavaMethodExecutorImpl.java:54)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod (JavaFunctionBroker.java:57)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute (InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute (InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle (MessageHandler.java:45)
   at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0 (JavaWorkerClient.java:92)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:511)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
   at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Do you have the full log for this scenario? Generally, the EventProducerClient is long-lived because creating an AMQP connection to the service takes time.

Comment: Do you create a client instance before sending each batch and close immediately after? You mentioned " In my application logs I see the following exception displaying once in every two days", so, it seems like the creation of client fails (the builder is throwing the exception) and the dataBatch is not even created to send. It would be great if you could share the logs and also a standalone sample to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ConnieYau I have added from the monitoring application insights . So the above is the entire log that is getting displayed

Comment: @srikanta Yes what you see in the above code is how i am doing it. Creating a client -> Sending the data -> Closing the client

Comment: It's recommended to create a single client and use it to send multiple event batches instead of creating one client instance for every batch.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the sample code which will check whether the data is sent completely or not and it will continue to do so until everything is sent.

```
import  com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.*;

import  java.util.Arrays;

import  java.util.List;

public  class  Sender {

private  static  final  String  connectionString = "<Event Hubs namespace connection string>";

private  static  final  String  eventHubName = "<Event hub name>";

/**

* Code sample for publishing events.

* @throws  IllegalArgumentException if the EventData is bigger than the max batch size.

*/

public  static  void  publishEvents() {

// create a producer client

EventHubProducerClient  producer = new  EventHubClientBuilder()

.connectionString(connectionString, eventHubName)

.buildProducerClient();

// sample events in an array

List<EventData> allEvents = Arrays.asList(new  EventData("Foo"), new  EventData("Bar"));

// create a batch

EventDataBatch  eventDataBatch = producer.createBatch();

for (EventData  eventData  :  allEvents) {

// try to add the event from the array to the batch

// continue to add the data if the data does not fit

while (!eventDataBatch.tryAdd(eventData)) {

// if the batch is full, send it and then create a new batch

producer.send(eventDataBatch);

eventDataBatch = producer.createBatch();

}

// Try to add that event that couldn't fit before.

if (!eventDataBatch.tryAdd(eventData)) {

throw  new  IllegalArgumentException("Event is too large for an empty batch. Max size: "

+ eventDataBatch.getMaxSizeInBytes());

}

}

// send the last batch of remaining events

if (eventDataBatch.getCount() > 0) {

producer.send(eventDataBatch);

}

producer.close();

}

public  static  void  main(String[] args) {

publishEvents();

}

}
```

Here is the Microsoft [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send) for complete information.